# Where do I place Firebase Check and Fix Dependencies code in Unity?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I wanted to use Firebase in my Unity game so one of the steps was to add the following code, but the place into which the code should be added wasn't specified. Any help?

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
  if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
    // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
    // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
       app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

    // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
  } else {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
      "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
    // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
  }
});
```

(This is the link to the instructions on Firebase)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup?authuser=0#confirm-google-play-version

Comment: It's entirely up to you to decide when you should perform this check in your app.  It might make sense to do it soon after it's launched.

Comment: I launched the game several months ago actually but I am struggling where to place this code as in the guide it says " Add the following code at the start of your application" which is not specific

Comment: It's not specific, because it's up to you to determine the best place for your particular app.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can give is "before you do anything else" in Unity.

In a normal application, you'd have something like a main api entry point (`application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in iOS, `Activity.onCreate` in Android, or literally `void main(int,char**)` in a typical C/C++ desktop application). But in Unity, you don't have any sort of "run this before everything else" logic. Whichever scene is first is up to you and subject to change, and scripts execute roughly in parallel (in an order that's best considered random but technically can be ordered).

Here are the patterns I've either used or have thought about using and a few associated pros and cons:

1. [Recommended for beginners and small projects] In my videos, I typically recommend having a "loading" or "setup" scene. In that scene I place a `FirebaseInit` script that will initialize Firebase and raise an event when it's done. I can then either collect a bunch of initialization functionality (say downloading asset bundles or doing some initial setup processing) or just jump immediately into my main scene. Most of the time this will resolve to a no-op (on Android play services is up to date), so you can even shove it in the main menu if you're careful:

```
using System;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;

public class FirebaseInit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnityEvent OnInitialized = new UnityEvent();
    public InitializationFailedEvent OnInitializationFailed = new InitializationFailedEvent();

    void Start()
    {
        FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            if (task.Exception != null)
            {
                OnInitializationFailed.Invoke(task.Exception);
            }
            else
            {
                OnInitialized.Invoke();
            }
        });
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class InitializationFailedEvent : UnityEvent<Exception>
    {
    }
}
```

2. I'm not a big proponent of dependency injection (as in I typically don't use DI frameworks, but I do tend to use `[SerializedField]`s as a pseudo-DI system), so I don't have a *good* example to share. You can use [ZenJect](https://github.com/modesttree/Zenject) to create and inject the Firebase singletons to anything that needs them. The biggest issue you run into is that you have to await the dependencies to be initialized, which is possible but I just haven't gone through the steps of doing it in a sample project. The benefit is that you only need to express "I depend on Firebase", and ZenJect will take care of the rest (just avoid the `DefaultInstance` functions in this case).
3. In more complex projects, I'll tend to wrap Firebase in a `Coroutine` (or an async task, but I prefer coroutines in Unity). So I'll have a `Coroutine` that will wait for check and fix dependencies to complete and return an instance of Realtime Database when it finishes (and intelligent logic to skip the waiting if not necessary). Again you have to avoid `DefaultInstance` outside of your management script, and every use of Firebase becomes a coroutine, but you can be sure that you always await on construction. Here is one example focusing on Realtime Database (I'm stripping unnecessary code to make it fit in a SO answer), and I'll reiterate that this is a lot of overhead for a small project:

```
public class FirebaseBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    private IEnumerator _setupFirebase;
    private DatabaseReference _databaseReference;

    void Awake()
    {
        // everything depends on firebase being setup. Do this first.
        _setupFirebase = SetupFirebase();
        StartCoroutine(_setupFirebase);
    }

    private IEnumerator SetupFirebase()
    {
        // we need to fix dependencies on Android
        if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android && !Application.isEditor)
        {
            Debug.Log("Checking dependencies on Android");
            var checkDependencies = new TaskYieldInstruction<DependencyStatus>(FirebaseApp.CheckDependenciesAsync());
            yield return checkDependencies;
            Debug.Log($"Check Dependencies: {checkDependencies.Result}");
        }

        _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Safely gets a database reference at the given path
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">The path at which to get a reference</param>
    /// <returns>A yield instruction that can be yielded in a coroutine</returns>
    public GetDatabaseReferenceYieldInstruction GetDatabaseReference(string path)
    {
        return new GetDatabaseReferenceYieldInstruction(path, _setupFirebase);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronously gets a database reference at the given path after a predicate executes
    /// </summary>
    public class GetDatabaseReferenceYieldInstruction : IEnumerator
    {
        private IEnumerator _predicate;
        private readonly string _path;
        public DatabaseReference Root { get; private set; }

        public GetDatabaseReferenceYieldInstruction(string path, IEnumerator predicate)
        {
            _path = path;
            _predicate = predicate;
        }
        
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_predicate != null)
            {
                if (_predicate.MoveNext())
                {
                    return true;
                }

                _predicate = null;
                
                // TODO: this is a cross cutting concern to inject
                Root = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference.Child(_path);
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
        }

        public object Current => Root;
    }
}
```

Which you can use like this:

```
[SerializeField] private FirebaseSingleton _firebaseSingleton;
public void Awake()
{
    _firebase = _firebaseSingleton.Instance;
    _getDatabase = _firebase.GetDatabaseReference(DatabaseName);
}

private IEnumerator RegisterForEvents()
{
    yield return _getDatabase;
    _getPigDatabase.Root.ValueChanged += HandlePigValuesChanged;
}
```

4. With [Unity's new DOTS system](https://unity.com/dots), I've been flirting with the idea of moving Unity's initialization into the [`OnCreate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.entities@0.14/api/Unity.Entities.ComponentSystemBase.html#Unity_Entities_ComponentSystemBase_OnCreate_) function for a system. Because you have a clean entrypoint, you'd be able to block Firebase functionality until it comes online, and you could control Firebase by injecting specific entities into the world with custom Firebase-specific components on it. I don't have a good example yet, although it's on my project backlog.

Comment: Note that for the ZenJect example (and to a lesser extent the Coroutine one), you can `CheckDependencies` synchronously ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/firebase-app#checkdependencies ), but you must resolve them asynchronously (since it involves showing a dialog prompting a player to update play services - then you have to wait for the install). That's the major thing adding complexity to every example but the first one.

Comment: I watched your videos but I was stuck as I wasn't able to find Window > Firebase > Documentation

Comment: It will only appear after you've added the Firebase SDK (a bit of a catch 22 - I know), and you _might_ need to ensure that there's a clean build in editor (ie: you don't have any errors in your editor log).

Comment: Nope, however you add Firebase (UPM or via unitypackage files), you just need to add the SDK that you intend to use. All other transitive dependencies are handled for you (aside: this is why the SDK zip file is so large, I always recommend UPM now if possible).

Comment: I found the documentation file but when I try to open it gives me another error:
TypeLoadException: Could not load type of field 'Firebase.Editor.SettingsWindow:measurementSettings' (1) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000005 (from typeref, class/assembly Google.EditorMeasurement, Google.VersionHandlerImpl, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null) assembly:Google.VersionHandlerImpl, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:Google.EditorMeasurement member:(null) signature:<none>

Comment: Huh, that's one I haven't seen before. My guess is that something bad is happening with editor analytics. I can't reproduce it quickly on my end, so I'd recommend filing an issue ( https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues ). It might have something to do with the "Enable Analytics Reporting" at the end of the Firebase window, but turning this off is not intended to have any ill effects and the team would want to fix that ASAP for obvious privacy related reasons.